How to swap the columns according to the data type?
The sample data is as below (The data is fake, not real data):



Key
Death indicator
Date Death
Exact date of death
Death Cause




00
Alive





02
Death hos
Y
25/9/2011
N00


03
Alive





09
Death hos
Y
J189
28/8/2015


07
Death nonhos
12/6/2018
Y
C20



From the table, you can see the types of data within the same columns are not consistent. Date Death should be in date format; Exact date of death should only contain Y, N or blank; Death Cause should be in string (i.e. ICD code).
I forgot to mention one important thing, the date format may not be consistent, e.g. '01-05-2010','01 May 2010' can also appear in the date columns.
I tried to perform some basic data cleaning:
Python:
import pandas as pd

death_y_n = death['Date Death'][pd.to_datetime(death['Date Death'], \
                                                                 format='%d/%m/%Y',
                                                                 errors = 'coerce')\
                                                                 .isnull()]

death_disease_case = death['Exact date of death'][~((death['Exact date of death'].isin(['Y','N']))\
                                                      |(death['Exact date of death'].isnull()))]

death['Death Cause'][~pd.to_datetime(\
                                      death['Death Cause'], \
                                      format='%d/%m/%Y', errors = 'coerce')\
                                      .isnull()] = \
                                      death_disease_case

death['Date Death'][pd.to_datetime(\
                                      death['Date Death'], \
                                      format='%d/%m/%Y', errors = 'coerce')\
                                      .isnull()] = \
                                      death_to_date[pd.to_datetime(\
                                                                   death['Date Death'], \
                                                                   format='%d/%m/%Y', errors = 'coerce')\
                                                                   .isnull()]

death['Exact date of death'][~death['Exact date of death'].isin(['Y','N'])] = \
                                  death_y_n[~death['Exact date of death'].isin(['Y','N'])]

death['Death Cause'][pd.to_datetime(\
                                      death['Date Death'], \
                                      format='%d/%m/%Y', errors = 'coerce')\
                                      .isnull()] = \
                                       death_y_n[pd.to_datetime(\
                                      death['Date Death'], \
                                      format='mixed', errors = 'coerce')\
                                      .isnull()]

R:
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(anytime)
library(Hmisc)

death_to_date = anytime(death$`Death Cause`) %>% as.character

death_y_n = death$`Date Death`[is.na(as_date(death$`Date Death`))]

death_disease_case = death$`Exact date of death`[death$`Exact date of death` %nin% c('Y','N')]

death$`Death Cause`[!is.na(as_date(death$`Death Cause` ))] = death_disease_case[!is.na(as_date(death$`Death Cause` ))]

death$`Date of Registered Death`[is.na(as_date(death$`Date Death`))] = death_to_date[is.na(as_date(death$`Date Death`))]

death$`Exact date of death`[death$`Exact date of death` %nin% c('Y','N')] = death_y_n[death$`Exact date of death` %nin% c('Y','N')]

However, due to multiple formats of date, some date formats cannot be parsed successfully. Is there a method to swap the columns without using to_datetime()/anytime()?
I am new to Python, if there are any mistakes I made, please point them out! Thank you.
Updated:
My python solution:
import pandas as pd

#for death date variable save as exact date of death:'Y'/'N'
death_to_date_index_exact = (death['Date Death'].isin(['Y','N']))
death_to_date_exact = death['Date Death'][death_to_date_index_exact]

#for death cause variable save as date of death
death_cause_index_date = (~death['Death Cause'].str.contains('^[A-Za-z].*[0-9]$',na=True))
death_cause_date = death['Death Cause'][death_cause_index_date]

#for exact date of death variable save as death cause
death_exact_index_cause = (death['Exact date of death'].str.contains('^[A-Za-z].*[0-9]$',na=False))
death_exact_cause = death['Exact date of death'][death_exact_index_cause]

death['Date Death'][death_cause_index_date] = death_cause_date
death['Exact date of death'][death_to_date_index_exact] = death_to_date_exact
death['Death Cause'][death_exact_index_cause] = death_exact_cause

#Convert the date in death cause into empty
death['Death Cause'][~death['Death Cause'].str.contains('^[A-Za-z].*[0-9]$',na=True)] = np.nan


post your solution as a solution, don't add it to your question, it makes it harder for later readers to find

There's a few different ways you can do this. The simplest way to me, which doesn't require creating a new vector three times, is to create a named list in R, then unnest it wider, as follows:
library(tidyverse)
  
df |>
  mutate(sorted = pmap(list(Date.Death, Exact.date.of.death, Death.Cause), \(...) {out <- list()
  for (x in c(...)) { # for each row of the three columns above
    if (x %in% c("Y", "N", NA)) { # we do this one first, otherwise the NAs throw things off
      out$Exact.date.of.death <- x 
    } else if (grepl("/", x)) {
      out$Date.Death <- x
    } else {
      out$Death.Cause <- x
    }
  }
  out
  }), .keep = "unused") |> # drop the columns we used (i.e. Date.Death, Exact.date.of.death, Death.Cause)
  unnest_wider(sorted) # then unnest the named list column, making new versions of them!

Output:
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  Key   Death.indicator Exact.date.of.death Date.Death Death.Cause
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>               <chr>      <chr>      
1 Alive NA              NA                  NA         NA         
2 Death hos             Y                   25/9/2011  N00        
3 Alive NA              NA                  NA         NA         
4 Death hos             Y                   28/8/2015  J189       
5 Death nonhos          Y                   12/6/2018  C20        

Data:
df <- read.table(text="Key  Death.indicator     Date.Death  Exact.date.of.death     Death.Cause
00  Alive NA NA NA NA
02  Death hos   Y   25/9/2011   N00
03  Alive NA NA NA NA       
09  Death hos   Y   J189    28/8/2015
07  Death nonhos    12/6/2018   Y   C20", header=TRUE)

Notes:

You've said you've had trouble parsing your dates. It would be helpful if you could give some examples of the dates you are struggling to parse.
Your data still needs some cleaning - for instance, "Y" and "N" should be TRUE and FALSE. Also if the data is death data, then it would make sense to remove the Alive ones, they add nothing. Also, blanks should NA.


I forgot to mention one important thing, the date format may not be consistent, e.g. '01-05-2010' can also appear in the date columns. Your idea is awesome without using any dummy variables!

@doraemon ah okay. That is just one example. If we are using grep, we need all variations. I've answered too many questions where the user asks for A, I solve A, then they tell me it had to match B too, i change it to match B too, and then repeat for C, D etc

01-05-2010 cannot be parsed without context as it could be May 1 or Jan 5

Dates are tricky, but you might want to check out the lubridate package. What errors does the R code throw? If you're getting stopped by errors I would suggest starting the dates out as a character column, getting all the data in the same column, then parse the NA values. Once you have everything in the correct format, then coerce the column to date format. Since the character column will accept your changes, you'll be able to do whatever cleaning you need to do.  The problem with coercing to date format on the first step is that often these generic conversion functions like as.date() are very picky. If any one value is in the wrong format, the whole thing will fail and throw an error. So if  you're getting caught up in that, try doing that conversion with anytime in the last step and see if you don't have better results.

I have tried anytime,  lubridate, and base r::as.date() and still could not parse some date formats (or some formats that I missed). That's why I want to use the other 2 formats ('Y','N', ICD10) instead of date.
